# how to use onclick javascript function for input tag html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `input` tag acting as a `button`, which is working fine, but now I am trying to implement something that I need to use a script for. So I want to call the function using onclick, but it is not working with an input tag. How do I do this. Here's what I have:

```
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="spinner()">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function spinner() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = "block";
      var username = document.getElementById('login__username').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('login__password').value;
      fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
              })
            })
  }
```

works nicely, however, it only works when it is a `button` and I call that function, but not an `input` tag. How do I do this?

Comment: any submit will refresh the page, so your code action is lost in the previous page loading

Comment: if it works fine as a `button` why do you need it to be an `input`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

```
 <button style="width: 100%;" onclick="spinner()"><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></button>
```

although this isn't the greatest option, it works, and works great. It is easier to style it this way as well!

Answer (score 0):

Modify `onclick="spinner()"` to `onclick="spinner(event)"`.
Update `function spinner()` signature to `function spinner(e)` 
Add `e.preventDefault();` at the end the `spinner()` function.
Execute the promise appropriately -

```
fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })
}).then(r => r.json().then(j => console.log(j)));
```

Comment: it didn't change anything, but I think it is because I am trying to fetch a function from within my script function.